# SQL Server openquery() with stored proc not returning data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc that returns some data (just 1 row of dates). When I just call this proc with exec I get the returned data and all is good.

I want to make this accessible via a view so I use openquery() to do that. However when I do that I get the error message:

```
Cannot process the object "exec GetDates". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LOCAL" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
```

I've noticed it's the insert statement on the temp table. If I comment that out then I don't get this error. So I assume it's the permission side of that error message. It's a temp table, how can I not have permission to insert into that when I can insert into any real table in the database?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDates]
AS
    DECLARE @capacityTable TABLE (dt datetime)
    DECLARE @dt datetime
    DECLARE curDates CURSOR FOR SELECT dt from calendar;

    -- loop over all dates we care about
    OPEN curDates;
    FETCH NEXT FROM curDates INTO @dt;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @capacityTable (dt)
        VALUES(@dt)

        FETCH NEXT FROM curDates INTO @dt;
    END;
    CLOSE curDates;
    DEALLOCATE curDates;

    -- return the temp table results
    SELECT dt from @capacityTable;
RETURN

alter view GetDates_vw
as
select * from openquery(LOCAL, 'exec GetDates')
```

Comment: Note that this is just a building block to what I actually need so I'm aware this example doesn't make sense. I'm adding to this as I'm newer to T-SQL and figuring things out as I go.

Comment: Try fully qualifying your objects - db.schema.object

Comment: How would that look for a temp table? I tried db.schema.@capacityTable but it gives syntax error when compiling the proc.

Comment: Not needed for the **table variable** (not temp table).  Do it for calendar, GetDates_vw, and GetDates.  I'm not sure that will fix it, but it's the right place to start.

Comment: Didn't seem to solve it. The strange thing is running this works: exec dbo.GetCargillCapacity, but I want to do this as a view. So something going through the linked server which points back itself.

Comment: Can we get around this by upgrading your SP?  I know you stated this is a dumbed down version, but in this example you're selecting into a table variable from within a cursor.  Maybe post the real SP to see if we can change it.

Comment: This is the only version as it stands. I'm building the proc up. First step is to loop over the dates table. Inside I'll be running queries using the date against 2 tables to determine if records exist and which ones to use (there is a pecking order) and then inserting the results to a in memory table that will have more fields than this. So this was just a test to see that I can do this before I get too involved in the rest of the other stuff. Starting simple to validate things are possible since I'm newer to T-SQL.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like before the EXEC in the openquery() function if you place SET NOCOUNT ON; it works. Not sure why but it does.

Comment: It works because "SET NOOUNT ON;" supresses the trace lines one normaly puts in to body of a SP for debug purposes, and only the query result is being processed.